# Multiple graphs in the same window

Tags: matlab

i have a function that gets few parameters and plots a graph in Matlab
i want to use the function to plot few graphs with different parameters in one window.
i tried "subplot" but it doesn't do it.
is there a way doing it?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `hold on` and in the end `hold off`

Further information: http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/hold.html

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one more thing in C. Colden suggestion, Provide the same x values for all plot as shown below:

```
x = 0:0.01:pi ;
y1 = sind(x) ;
y2= codd(x) ;
plot (x,y1)
hold on
plot(x,y2)
```

if you want to provide x1 and x2 for x values, then you will encounter with an error.